# Create 2D bar code that contains back-tab

Tags: 2d, barcode, ipl

Is it possible, and if so how, do I create a 2D bar code using IPL, intermec programming language, that contains human readable text, TAB, and BACK-TAB. The goal is to print the bar code that can then be scanned on a different computer that we have no control over. The software running on the PC contains fields that would be populate based on the information contained in the bar code along with TAB, BACK-TAB, and SPACE. The goal is to print the bar code containing numerous information and keystrokes that will allow the users to simply scan the 2D bar code which will fill out all information on their workstation.

I have tried  to emulate the shift-in, Tab, and shift-out but nothing seems to work.

I read several article that indicate I can do this, and several that indicate I cannot. Neither list clear reason why this will or will not work.

Comment: Almost a duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30904203/2568535

Comment: The same principles apply despite the fact that it discusses Code 128 rather than some 2D format.