# Barcode39 print tab key along with barcode

Tags: crystal-reports, barcode, code39

Requirement is like, I've 2 textboxes and only one barcode. when i scan the barcode, both textboxes should get filled with value. navigate from one textbox to another textbox is tab control (default)

textbox 1 (Name), and textbox 2 (Age). barcode input will be like Name**\t**Age. input will be encode into barcode. when user scans, both textboxes should get filled.

i am using crystal report with built in azalea additional function BarcodeC39ASCII

i've referred different forums and few of them suggested to use $I. which is not working.

Comment: what exactly your requirement, do you want to use Barcode39 or $I? are you read :-http://www.azalea.com/code-39/crystal-reports/

Comment: i am using BarcodeC39ASCII("Name$IAge") function to bring the name and age into separate textbox. but it is not working.  i am using Symbol DS9808 scanner

Comment: "$I" is indeed the correct shift combination in a Code 39 Full ASCII symbol to encode a horizontal tab character (HT; ASCII 9). Please refer to the "General effect of scanning barcodes containing ASCII control characters" section of the following answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30904203/2568535