# Need A Specific Barcode Created

Tags: barcode, barcode-scanner, barcode-printing

Alright, So I work for a retail store and their POS Login doesnt have the option to create a "Fast ID" I know that it is possible as when i worked at target we could do it.

I know that ^009 gives tab but I don't know what barcode is needed

I Need It To fill Out 2 Fields

Username: 61280
(Tab)
Password: qaqa1122
(Enter)

Comment: You're going to need to provide more details to get any answers. What platform are you using? Is this a coding question?

Comment: It is technically a coding question. the platform doesn't matter the scanners will pick up any barcode/label type. If you don't know how to help, whats the point in commenting? also if you notice the tagging, you would notice that it is not tagged under anything besides barcode related.

Comment: The comment box placeholder says "Use comments to ask for more information or suggest improvements. Avoid answering questions in comments." I was going through the review queue for new user questions and was trying to help you get an answer. I admit I am unfamiliar with barcodes, so I apologize for that.

Comment: Alright fair enough. I could have reacted better aswell. no hard feelings. I'm sure you didnt mean to come off as rude. been a long day today. haha so kinda on edge. :D

Comment: The following might be helpful, or at least make you aware of broader issues with form-based data entry using barcodes: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30904203/2568535