# Print barcode with "TAB", "ENTER" in Python

Tags: python-3.x, barcode

I need to write a program for create barcodes. When the barcode will be scanned, it must send a string, a TAB (simulate key press) and a new string.
Then I'd like to compile multiple fields in a form.
Can you suggest me a library?
I tried python-barcode, reBarcode etc. but I don't understand if it is possible to insert the "TAB" key.
Grazie

Answer (score 0):

The library used to create the barcodes usually does not matter.

You just need to select a barcode type that supports the full ASCII character set.  Some examples are code128 (linear barcode) or datamatrix and qrcode (2D barcodes).

And you also need a software-based "wedge" that converts the stream of characters coming in from the USB or wireless port into their equivalent key presses.  The following provides a good overview of the process:

[TAB key in Code128 barcodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30895388/tab-key-in-code128-barcodes)