# Barcode39 translating tab function incorrectly

Tags: ascii, barcode, barcode-scanner

I'm trying to help my colleagues to fill out a web form with multiple fields faster through an automated barcode.
The barcode would be code39 and would be generated as follows: 'Name**Tab**LicensePlate**Tab**etc'.

Through research I have found that I need to use '$I' in my barcode to make a horizontal tab but when I try this it seems that my scanner is translating it as CTRL+I. I am using a Symbol LS2208 barcode scanner and have tried enabling the function key mapping but it still doesn't create a tab. The barcode is full ASCII as wel.

Does anyone know of this issue and perhaps a possible fix?
I have spent hours going through the manual and google for help on this matter but I can't find any solution to my problem. I am hoping someone has knowledge of this issue and could help me out.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: For keyboard input emulation, tab key press and Ctrl + I press notifications seem to be equivalent. For example, try pressing each key while entering text in the editor. In most cases, both will do the same.

Comment: That does explain the issue I'm facing :(. Anyway around this? Perhaps a different code format (128 instead of 39) or not using a keyboard emulation?

Comment: TAB is from the Extended Code 39 family.  Can you check and make sure your scanner is set for Extended?  It looks like it's reading standard Code 39 if you're getting the literal characters instead of the tab

Comment: If the scanner's Code39FullASCII setting is enabled, receiving Ctrl+I or Tab would be correct. Since Ctrl+I and Tab are equivalent, should the same operation be performed regardless of which notification is given? Or if you want to receive $I, why not disable the Code39FullASCII setting?

Comment: I need to receive a tab as I want it to jump to the next field and fill in the correct information. CTRL+I however is opening the favorites in internet explorer (which is where the web form is used in our warehouse management system). So if my barcode is 'Stackoverflow$Icode39' it would fill in Stackoverflow and then open the favorites tab and do nothing anymore. So unfortunately I really need the scanner/PC to read it as TAB and not as ctrl+I.
With extended code I guess u mean FULLASCII? In which case, yes I've tried turning that on already but didn't help :(

Comment: If the tab key is not notified and Ctrl+I is notified even if the Function Key Mapping setting is enabled on page 94(6-8) of the LS2208 product reference guide at the same time as Code39FullASCII, it is better to contact the scanner reseller or vendor.

Comment: I'll contact the reseller of the scanner and in the meantime I'll try to get a hold of a different scanner in our company to find out if perhaps i've been using a broken scanner. Thanks for the help kunif!

Answer (score 0):

```html
<h3> If this works, I suggest you switch to Code128 A and B unless you can do without lowercase, if so, you can use Code 128A only. <h3> <br>
<center>
<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/ASL/AADeAAAA/gAAAAIAAAD+AAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAh6QEAZKdo54AAAAASUVORK5CYII=" style="width:7px;height:50px;"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/Af//AAABAAAA/wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAcjEDAghkmFUAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" style="width:7px;height:50px;"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/Af//AAABAAAA/wAAAAEAAAAAAAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAck4DAxY8F10AAAAASUVORK5CYII=" style="width:7px;height:50px;"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/AQD/AAD/AAAAAAAAAAAAAAABAAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAATUoCA+Jw8kAAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" style="width:7px;height:50px;"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/AQD/AAD/AAAAAQAAAP8AAAAAAAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAajUDAvnk9E4AAAAASUVORK5CYII=" style="width:7px;height:50px;"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/AQD/AAD/AAAAAQAAAAAAAAD/AAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAZjkDAtle3bIAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" style="width:7px;height:50px;"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/Af//AAAAAAAAAAAAAAEAAAAAAAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAUUoCA+juoggAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" style="width:7px;height:50px;"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/AQD/AAAAAAAA/wAAAAEAAAAAAAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAASVICA62zYxMAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" style="width:7px;height:50px;"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/AQD/AAD/AAAAAQAAAP8AAAABAAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAak4DA7VAmk0AAAAASUVORK5CYII=" style="width:7px;height:50px;"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/Af//AAABAAAAAAAAAP8AAAAAAAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAbjUDAlvFFR8AAAAASUVORK5CYII=" style="width:7px;height:50px;"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/AQD/AAD/AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAATTECAq7UnEMAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" style="width:7px;height:50px;"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/AQD/AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAD/AAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAQT0CAkdoxRUAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" style="width:7px;height:50px;"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/AQD/AAD/AAAAAAAAAAAAAAABAAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAATUoCA+Jw8kAAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" style="width:7px;height:50px;"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/Af//AAABAAAA/wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAcjEDAghkmFUAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" style="width:7px;height:50px;"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/Af//AAABAAAAAAAAAP8AAAABAAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAbk4DAxdhexwAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" style="width:7px;height:50px;"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/Af//AAAAAAAAAQAAAP8AAAAAAAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAbjEDAjQrOn0AAAAASUVORK5CYII=" style="width:7px;height:50px;"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/Af//AAABAAAAAAAAAP8AAAABAAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAbk4DAxdhexwAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" style="width:7px;height:50px;"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/ASL/AADeAAAA/gAAAAIAAAD+AAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAh6QEAZKdo54AAAAASUVORK5CYII=" style="width:7px;height:50px;"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/Af//AAAAAAAAAAAAAAEAAAAAAAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAUUoCA+juoggAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" style="width:7px;height:50px;"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/Af//AAABAAAA/wAAAAAAAAABAAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAckoDA0TA9lYAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" style="width:7px;height:50px;"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/Af//AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABAAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAUUYCA7QBErsAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" style="width:7px;height:50px;"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/Af//AAABAAAAAAAAAP8AAAAAAAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAbjUDAlvFFR8AAAAASUVORK5CYII=" style="width:7px;height:50px;"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/AQD/AAD/AAAAAQAAAAAAAAD/AAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAZjkDAtle3bIAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" style="width:7px;height:50px;"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/Af//AAABAAAA/wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAcjEDAghkmFUAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" style="width:7px;height:50px;"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/Af//AAABAAAAAAAAAP8AAAAAAAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAbjUDAlvFFR8AAAAASUVORK5CYII=" style="width:7px;height:50px;"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/Af//AAAAAAAAAQAAAP8AAAABAAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAbkoDA3iPVH4AAAAASUVORK5CYII=" style="width:7px;height:50px;"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/Af//AAAAAAAAAQAAAP8AAAABAAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAbkoDA3iPVH4AAAAASUVORK5CYII=" style="width:7px;height:50px;"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/AQD/AAAAAAAAAAAAAP8AAAAAAAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAARTkCAqx1lb4AAAAASUVORK5CYII=" style="width:7px;height:50px;"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/AQD/AAD/AAAAAAAAAAEAAAD/AAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAZjUDAmZGozoAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" style="width:7px;height:50px;"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/AQD/AAAAAAAA/wAAAAAAAAABAAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAASU4CA+16cNAAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" style="width:7px;height:50px;"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/Af//AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABAAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAUUYCA7QBErsAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" style="width:7px;height:50px;"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/AQD/AAAAAAAA/wAAAAEAAAAAAAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAASVICA62zYxMAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" style="width:7px;height:50px;"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/AQD/AAD/AAAAAQAAAAAAAAD/AAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAZjkDAtle3bIAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" style="width:7px;height:50px;"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/AQD/AAAAAAAA/wAAAAAAAAABAAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAASU4CA+16cNAAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" style="width:7px;height:50px;"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/Af//AAABAAAA/wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAcjEDAghkmFUAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" style="width:7px;height:50px;"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/Af//AAABAAAA/wAAAAAAAAABAAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAckoDA0TA9lYAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" style="width:7px;height:50px;"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/Af//AAABAAAAAAAAAP8AAAAAAAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAbjUDAlvFFR8AAAAASUVORK5CYII=" style="width:7px;height:50px;"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/Af//AAAAAAAAAQAAAP8AAAAAAAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAbjEDAjQrOn0AAAAASUVORK5CYII=" style="width:7px;height:50px;"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/AQD/AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAD/AAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAQT0CAkdoxRUAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" style="width:7px;height:50px;"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/AQD/AAD/AAAAAAAAAAEAAAD/AAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAZjUDAmZGozoAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" style="width:7px;height:50px;"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/AQD/AAAAAAAA/wAAAAAAAAABAAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAASU4CA+16cNAAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" style="width:7px;height:50px;"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/Af//AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABAAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAUUYCA7QBErsAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" style="width:7px;height:50px;"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/AQD/AAAAAAAAAAAAAP8AAAABAAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAARVICA/z3WM0AAAAASUVORK5CYII=" style="width:7px;height:50px;"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/Af//AAAAAAAAAAAAAAEAAAD/AAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAajEDAm49ReYAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" style="width:7px;height:50px;"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/AQD/AAD/AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAATTECAq7UnEMAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" style="width:7px;height:50px;"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/ASL/AADeAAAA/gAAAAIAAAD+AAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAh6QEAZKdo54AAAAASUVORK5CYII=" style="width:7px;height:50px;"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/Af//AAABAAAA/wAAAAEAAAAAAAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAck4DAxY8F10AAAAASUVORK5CYII=" style="width:7px;height:50px;"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/Af//AAAAAAAAAQAAAP8AAAAAAAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAbjEDAjQrOn0AAAAASUVORK5CYII=" style="width:7px;height:50px;"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/Af//AAAAAAAAAQAAAP8AAAAAAAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAbjEDAjQrOn0AAAAASUVORK5CYII=" style="width:7px;height:50px;"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/AQD/AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAD/AAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAQT0CAkdoxRUAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" style="width:7px;height:50px;"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/AQD/AAD/AAAAAAAAAAEAAAD/AAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAZjUDAmZGozoAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" style="width:7px;height:50px;"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/Af//AAAAAAAAAAAAAAEAAAD/AAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAajEDAm49ReYAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" style="width:7px;height:50px;"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/AQD/AAAAAAAA/wAAAAAAAAABAAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAASU4CA+16cNAAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" style="width:7px;height:50px;"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/Af//AAABAAAAAAAAAP8AAAABAAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAbk4DAxdhexwAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" style="width:7px;height:50px;"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/AQD/AAAAAAAA/wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAASTUCAqHeHtMAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" style="width:7px;height:50px;"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/AQD/AAAAAAAA/wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAASTUCAqHeHtMAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" style="width:7px;height:50px;"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/AQD/AAAAAAAAAAAAAP8AAAABAAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAARVICA/z3WM0AAAAASUVORK5CYII=" style="width:7px;height:50px;"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/Af//AAABAAAAAAAAAP8AAAAAAAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAbjUDAlvFFR8AAAAASUVORK5CYII=" style="width:7px;height:50px;">

</center>
```

Comment: Hi Brian, unfortunately nothing happens when I try to scan the barcode. It's able to scan CODE128 barcodes that I create so not sure why I'm not able to scan your example?

Comment: Are you scanning a printed or screen version? I am able to scan either with my DS6707-SR. Some scanners cannot read barcodes from screens, but it may be a configuration issue. I would like to see an example of the barcodes you produce that you can scan with your equipment.

Comment: Hi Brian, I am scanning a printed version, screen version doesn't work with my scanner. I am producing my barcodes on the following site: https://barcode.tec-it.com/en/Code39?data=CODE39%24ITAB. I tested today with a different scanner but had the same results (text goes italic instead of tab). I also tried the following barcode (first answer on this topic) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30895388/tab-key-in-code128-barcodes. But also this 128 code only caused my text to go italic and not tab.

Comment: @Leswouter - Ahhh. It becomes clear. CTRL-I is the tab character. The problem is not with your barcode, or printer or scanner. The problem is with your input field. The input field in your application needs to stop doing the conversion from CTRL-I (HT) to the {switch-to-italic} function. This happens in word processors or WYSIWYG fields where typefaces are manipulated. Try changing the input cursor focus to a text editor (notepad for windows) and scan the original barcode with the original scanner. I suspect the scanner is doing its job. Whatever your input field, that's probably the culprit.

Comment: Hi Brian, indeed in notepad it works perfectly... any way to ignore or change the input field on a web page? If I try the barcode on the webpage it is opening the favorites tab (because of the CTRL+I key), not sure if there's a way to tell the input field to not do this? Thanks already for your help! :)

Comment: Unfortunately, to intercept the barcode scanner's "keystrokes" and interpret the <HT> character as a tab and proceed to the next tabstop on the page you need to use a little client-side JavaScript, using addEventListener on the textarea. The sample code on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key describes the basic JS needed to intercept the "keys". Then you would have to add code to screen for the ctrl-i sequence and set the focus to the next field with HTMLElement.focus(). Your code will need to scan for the tabindex attribute and keep track of proper tab order.