# Ctrl+c and Ctrl+v to a barcode

Tags: ascii, barcode

How do I emulate key function Ctrl+c and Ctrl+v to a barcode so i can scan the barcode with a scanner. I've tried reading the ASCII Control Codes ASCII control codes
Please help me.

Comment: If you mean 1D barcode, it can only store numbers, like product number or ISBN.

Comment: Any barcode contains only numbers or characters. So the barcode reader will only deliver numbers and characters. What you do with them is totally up to you.

Comment: What technology/programming language is your project using? Also scanners can usually "auto-paste" the numbers the scanned barcode represents.

Comment: See the advice concerning "key presses" here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30904203/2568535

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use the Code 128A symbology and use a program that generates the barcode according to the ASCII lowercase of the control character you want to use.

```js
// The MIT License (MIT)
// Copyright (c) 2019, Notionovus, LLC.

var arrayCode128Bin = [ '11011001100', '11001101100', '11001100110', '10010011000', '10010001100', '10001001100', '10011001000', '10011000100', '10001100100', '11001001000', '11001000100', '11000100100', '10110011100', '10011011100', '10011001110', '10111001100', '10011101100', '10011100110', '11001110010', '11001011100', '11001001110', '11011100100', '11001110100', '11101101110', '11101001100', '11100101100', '11100100110', '11101100100', '11100110100', '11100110010', '11011011000', '11011000110', '11000110110', '10100011000', '10001011000', '10001000110', '10110001000', '10001101000', '10001100010', '11010001000', '11000101000', '11000100010', '10110111000', '10110001110', '10001101110', '10111011000', '10111000110', '10001110110', '11101110110', '11010001110', '11000101110', '11011101000', '11011100010', '11011101110', '11101011000', '11101000110', '11100010110', '11101101000', '11101100010', '11100011010', '11101111010', '11001000010', '11110001010', '10100110000', '10100001100', '10010110000', '10010000110', '10000101100', '10000100110', '10110010000', '10110000100', '10011010000', '10011000010', '10000110100', '10000110010', '11000010010', '11001010000', '11110111010', '11000010100', '10001111010', '10100111100', '10010111100', '10010011110', '10111100100', '10011110100', '10011110010', '11110100100', '11110010100', '11110010010', '11011011110', '11011110110', '11110110110', '10101111000', '10100011110', '10001011110', '10111101000', '10111100010', '11110101000', '11110100010', '10111011110', '10111101110', '11101011110', '11110101110', '11010000100', '11010010000', '11010011100', '1100011101011', '11010111000'];
var array5bit_A = [ 'f//AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA', 'f//AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAB', 'f//AAAAAAAAAAAAAAEAAAD/', 'f//AAAAAAAAAAAAAAEAAAAA', 'f//AAAAAAAAAQAAAP8AAAAA', 'f//AAAAAAAAAQAAAP8AAAAB', 'f//AAAAAAAAAQAAAAAAAAD/', 'f//AAAAAAAAAQAAAAAAAAAA', 'f//AAABAAAA/wAAAAAAAAAA', 'f//AAABAAAA/wAAAAAAAAAB', 'f//AAABAAAA/wAAAAEAAAD/', 'f//AAABAAAA/wAAAAEAAAAA', 'f//AAABAAAAAAAAAP8AAAAA', 'f//AAABAAAAAAAAAP8AAAAB', 'f//AAABAAAAAAAAAAAAAAD/', 'f//AAABAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA', 'QD/AAD/AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA', 'QD/AAD/AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAB', 'QD/AAD/AAAAAAAAAAEAAAD/', 'QD/AAD/AAAAAAAAAAEAAAAA', 'QD/AAD/AAAAAQAAAP8AAAAA', 'QD/AAD/AAAAAQAAAP8AAAAB', 'QD/AAD/AAAAAQAAAAAAAAD/', 'QD/AAD/AAAAAQAAAAAAAAAA', 'QD/AAAAAAAA/wAAAAAAAAAA', 'QD/AAAAAAAA/wAAAAAAAAAB', 'SL/AADeAAAA/gAAAAIAAAD+', 'QD/AAAAAAAA/wAAAAEAAAAA', 'QD/AAAAAAAAAAAAAP8AAAAA', 'QD/AAAAAAAAAAAAAP8AAAAB', 'QD/AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAD/', 'QD/AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA'];
var array5bit_B = [ 'US0CAuSD38g', 'UUYCA7QBErs', 'ajEDAm49ReY', 'UUoCA+juogg', 'bjEDAjQrOn0', 'bkoDA3iPVH4', 'ajUDAt82atY', 'UU4CA1nljTg', 'cjEDAghkmFU', 'ckoDA0TA9lY', 'izUEAhrxcbg', 'ck4DAxY8F10', 'bjUDAlvFFR8', 'bk4DAxdhexw', 'ajkDAr7LFAw', 'UVICAyQ+UJI', 'TTECAq7UnEM', 'TUoCA+Jw8kA', 'ZjUDAmZGozo', 'TU4CA7CME0s', 'ajUDAvnk9E4', 'ak4DA7VAmk0', 'ZjkDAtle3bI', 'TVICAxOyzrM', 'STUCAqHeHtM', 'SU4CA+16cNA', 'h6QEAZKdo54', 'SVICA62zYxM', 'RTkCAqx1lb4', 'RVICA/z3WM0', 'QT0CAkdoxRU', 'KFYBA46vJCA'];
var stringStart = '<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAACCAQAAADLaIVbAAAANUlEQVQIHQEqANX/A';
var stringMid = 'AAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA';
var stringEnd = 'AAAAASUVORK5CYII=" style="width:';

function genBarcode(inputString, intWidth, intHeight) {
var arraySeq = [], i, intChunks, resultString;
var intRawmod = inputString.length % 5;
  for (i = 0; i < 5 - intRawmod; i += 1) {
    inputString += "0";
  }
  intChunks = inputString.length / 5;
  for (i = 0; i < intChunks; i += 1) {
    arraySeq[i] = parseInt(inputString.substr(i * 5, 5), 2);
  }
  resultString = "";
  for (i = 0; i < arraySeq.length; i += 1) {
    resultString += stringStart + array5bit_A[arraySeq[i]] + stringMid + array5bit_B[arraySeq[i]] + stringEnd + intWidth + 'px;height:' + intHeight + 'px;">';
  }
  return resultString;
}

function funcCode128A(strText) {
var j, intWeight, intWtProd = 0;
var strRaw = "";
var arrayData = [];
  arrayData[0] = 103;
  intWtProd = 103;
  for (j = 0; j < strText.length; j += 1) {
    arrayData[j + 1] = strText.charCodeAt(j) - 32;
    intWeight = j + 1;
    intWtProd += intWeight * arrayData[j + 1];
  }
  arrayData[j + 1] = intWtProd % 103;
  arrayData[j + 2] = 106;
  for (j = 0; j < arrayData.length; j += 1) {
    strRaw += arrayCode128Bin[arrayData[j]];
  }
  return(strRaw);
}
document.getElementById("result0").innerHTML = genBarcode(funcCode128A("m"), 4, 50);
document.getElementById("result1").innerHTML = genBarcode(funcCode128A("c"), 4, 50);
document.getElementById("result2").innerHTML = genBarcode(funcCode128A("j"), 4, 50);
document.getElementById("result3").innerHTML = genBarcode(funcCode128A("v"), 4, 50);
document.getElementById("result4").innerHTML = genBarcode(funcCode128A("p"), 4, 50);
document.getElementById("result8").innerHTML = genBarcode(funcCode128A("x"), 4, 50);
document.getElementById("result5").innerHTML = genBarcode(funcCode128A("h"), 4, 50);
document.getElementById("result6").innerHTML = genBarcode(funcCode128A(String.fromCharCode(127)), 4, 50);
```

```html
<head>
<title>Plain Vanilla JS Code 128A Barcodes</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" >
</head>
<body>
<div id="result0"></div>
Ctrl-M
<div id="result1"></div>
Ctrl-C
<div id="result2"></div>
Ctrl-J
<div id="result3"></div>
Ctrl-V
<div id="result4"></div>
Ctrl-P
<div id="result8"></div>
Ctrl-X
<div id="result5"></div>
Backspace
<div id="result6"></div>
DEL
</body>
```